# How to distinguish between user selecting an item and getSelectedValue()?

Tags: java, swing, list, listener

Is there any way to tell during the execution of the `valueChanged` method of a `ListSelectionListener` whether the user clicked the JList or whether `setSelectedIndex` was called by some other code?

Comment: swing? if yes, add swing to tags as well

Comment: no way. If you feel you need the distinction, typically the wiring logic between view and data isn't rich enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, no. But if the goal is to only execute something if the selection comes from the user, you may set a flag before selecting an index in the code to signal that the selection doesn't come from the user, or remove the listener and add it afterwards:

```
private void selectIndexInList(int index) {
    this.selectionComesFromTheCode = true;
    try {
        list.setSelectedIndex(index);
    }
    finally {
        this.selectionComesFromTheCode = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    if (!this.selectionComesFromTheCode) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. I will leave it a bit longer for other to suggest other solutions. Can't believe hope long I've spent on this when the answers so simple. +1

Comment: @JB Nizet I think that you can determine if selection came from keyboard or mouse, I saw simle code for JTable where is possible get that from ListSelection